# Can you 3 star a base without destroying a tesla that isn't triggered?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Is it required to destroy all Tesla towers to 3 star a base? What about those that don't get triggered?

For example, if I were to "hide a tesla" where it isn't likely to get triggered by an attacker will that help me in any way from getting 3-starred?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is necessary to destroy all teslas.

According to the wiki

> The only exception to this rule is that Hidden Teslas will reveal themselves once a base has incurred at least 51% damage, as they must be destroyed (along with all other buildings) in order to achieve 3 stars.

Comment: @Ben_Craig. So the answer is "No it is not possible". For you to get a third star you need to reach 100% base destruction, that means passing through the 51% where the teslas will be revealed therefore making it necessary to destroy them to get to 100% and therefore a three star.

Comment: Unless you meant "yes it is necessary to destroy all teslas" :)

Comment: @pnizzle updated for clarity

Answer (score 1):

I tried the hiding the hidden tesla strategy, it pops up automatically after your base is destroyed by a certain amount. the only good thing about doing this is that the attacker might not have enough time to get to the hidden tesla

Comment: That is exactly what the accepted answer says. This answer doesn't really add anything useful.

Comment: @JohnFx perhaps he was saying that hidden tesla can be tucked away to corners like builder huts, so that it pops up in middle and thereby wasting time. Might work in Th7 bases as they have less buildings. +1